# Pausing Multiple Runnables

Tags: java, android, runnable, resume, pause

I have a series of runnables that run one after the other depending on some if statements.  I have been trying for about a month to figure out how to pause and resume the runnables depending on which one is currently running.  I cannot get it to work.

This is currently what I am using for my pause method.  At the start of each runnable, I am putting a String into SharedPreferences which tells me which runnable I am currently in.  I then use that String to resume the current runnable in this pause method.  It is just not working.  It will pause, but then when I resume, it skips around to a different part of the runnable, or a different runnable all together; or it just skips to the end of the runnables.  Sometimes it just freezes and doesn't crash, but doesn't do anything.

```
public void Pause(View view){

    if (soundsOn == true){
        mplayerButtonClick.start();
    }
    if(resume == true) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
        handler.removeCallbacks(r2);
        handler.removeCallbacks(r3);
        handler.removeCallbacks(rest);
        handler.removeCallbacks(switching);
        pauseButton.setText("Resume");
        resume = false;
    }else{
        place = preferences.getString("place", "r");
        progress();
        if(place.equals("r")) {
            handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
        }
        if(place.equals("r2")) {
            handler.postDelayed(r2, 3000);
        }
        if(place.equals("r3")) {
            handler.postDelayed(r3, 3000);
        }
        if(place.equals("rest")) {
            handler.postDelayed(rest, 3000);
        }
        if(place.equals("switching")) {
            handler.postDelayed(switching, 3000);
        }
        pauseButton.setText("Pause");
        resume = true;
    }
}
```

**The progress() is referring to resuming the progress bar.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.  This has been driving me crazy for so long!  Thank you in advance for any suggestions!! :)